# How to intercept delete and advise user it is not possible?

Tags: breeze

I am starting to develop with Breeze.js and ASP MVC+WebApi Controllers. I am concerned about securities, as we should all be concerned about the possibility of a hacker coming into play. Now I did find the `BeforeSaveEntity` intercept and it does seem to be exactly what I want to use on the server side. I managed to get the security I want on the server side, but how do I deal with it on the client side, in my case with AngularJS, what and how should I catch the output and deal with it? Let me show you some code sample I use on the server side:

```
public class ConferenceContextProvider : EFContextProvider<ConferenceContext>
{
    public ConferenceContextProvider() : base() { }

    // Creating the BeforeSaveEntity for Security purposes, see more details at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider#SaveInterception
    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        // return false if we don’t want the entity saved.if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Role)
          && entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
        // return a map of those entities we want saved.
        return saveMap;
    }
}
```

and then on client side with AngularJS

```
// AngularJS DataService
function saveChanges() {
    if (manager.hasChanges()) {
        var promise =
            manager.saveChanges()
                   .catch(queryFailed)
                   .finally(function (data) {
                       toastr.success('Save to DB Succeeded');
                   });
    } else {
        toastr.warning("Nothing to save");
    };
}
```

How do I catch the result and deal with it? With Firebug I can see that the POST returns a JSON object with `Entities` array being filled (if user has access) or that same array being empty (if user has access denied). But if multiple changes happen, then the array might be filled with a portion of it applied. So what is the best approach on the client side with an access denied? Can someone give me a proper sample code on how to deal with acces denied? Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't quite understand why you wouldn't just catch the returned HTTP response and display the message it contains.  I am assuming you are throwing some sort of HTTP error and stuffing a message in there like "You can't delete this" so why not just take that message and display it to the user?

Comment: I am not since I do not know how or where to throw these errors, I assume you mean on server side? I took part of the code from the breeze web site on the `BeforeSaveEntity` but it doesn't show more then what I have in my question... Could you give an answer with code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the BeforeSaveEntity method will mean that on the server once the payload it received your server will call the BeforeSaveEntity method once for each entity *before* the entity is saved.  As the docs show if you return false it will simply not save the entity.  Take note of the following line -

> If the method returns false then the entity will be excluded from the
>   save. If the method throws an exception, the entire save is aborted
>   and the exception is returned to the client.

If you throw an HTTP error I *think* it should propagate properly you should be able to catch that error client side and display it.  This is assuming if a payload contains an entity to delete you want to cancel the whole save.

Example -

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
{
    // throw http exception if there is an entity flagged for deletion
    if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Role)&& entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){ Content = new StringContent("Cannot delete an entity") };

        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And on your client-side query where you have a queryFailed method (pseudo code, examine the error that is thrown to construct this properly) -

```
function queryFailed (error) {
    alert('Query failed - ' + error.message);
}
```

**If you want to save all the other entities *but* this one and then return custom errors in the response you can do that as well but that will take additional customization and that would probably be a much more detailed answer**

Comment: What is the `ControllerContext` from your response? Is it suppose to be `ConferenceContext` from my question? If so, I don't have a `.request()`, so I can't get it to work.

Comment: Just code swiped from another answer - if you are using WebAPI you should be able to throw an HTTPResponseException by passing in something similar.

Comment: I got it working with this `var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){ Content = new StringContent("Cannot delete an entity") };`, you could update your answer with it, but having to deal with Exceptions is not so much fun. Isn't there any way to simply return a text message instead? Sorry for being newbie on this, I'm learning .Net as well :S

Comment: The problem as I see it of only returning a text message is that Breeze will think that the save completed successfully unless you throw a proper HTTP error response.

Comment: I can't seem to find any better answers anywhere, so unless someone else reply with a better answer, I'll agree with you on this one.. Thanks again ;)